# How can I search for emails I sent to someone in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-search

In Outlook 2010 I often need to search for emails sent to someone from me.

According to this [Outlook support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da), I should use:

```
to:bobby
```

However that only works if I'm searching only in the "Sent Items" folder.

Since I don't have that setting turned on (nor do I want to change that setting), that search ends up showing me all emails sent to Bobby - from both myself and other people.

The best alternative I've come up with is:

```
to:bobby from:richard
```

Which is quite a lot to type just to achieve this and still ends up showing me emails if the sender has the same forename (or surname) as I do.

Guesses such as `from:me` and `in:sent` haven't worked.

Is there a better way?

Comment: a custom search saved in the search folder would just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typical, one minute after I post the question, I find the answer:

```
to:bobby folder:sent
```

will show only emails to Bobby from me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Outlook in a different language, **Folder:sent** does not work.

e.g. for Outlook in German language, you need to type: **folder:gesendet**.
Obviously, folder:gesendete Elemente does not work.

Took me a while to figure out. I hope this helps to you!